# Java Jackson failed to construct BeanSerializer

Tags: java, json, jackson

Question from a Java beginner.
I have this class:

```
package ca.intfast.code;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Campaign implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int campaignId;
    private Country targetedCountry;
    private String targetedDomain;
    private ArrayList<BannerSize> availableBannerSizeList;
    
    // Constructors:

    public Campaign() { // needed for serialization
        super();
    };

    public Campaign(int campaignId, Country targetedCountry, String targetedDomain, ArrayList<BannerSize> availableBannerSizeList) {
        super();
        this.setCampaignId(campaignId);
        this.setTargetedDomain(targetedDomain);
        this.setTargetedCountry(targetedCountry);
        this.setTargetedDomain(targetedDomain);
        this.setAvailableBannerSizeList(availableBannerSizeList);
    }
    
    // Methods:
    
    public String getDomainOfTargetedDomain() {
        return Util.extractDomainName(getTargetedDomain()); // "https://toronto.com/" >>> "toronto.com"
    }
    
    // Getters/setters:
    
    public int getCampaignId() {
        return campaignId;
    }
    public void setCampaignId(int campaignId) {
        if (campaignId < 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException(campaignId + " must be positive.");
        this.campaignId = campaignId;
    }
    
    public Country getTargetedCountry() {
        return targetedCountry;
    }
    public void setTargetedCountry(Country targetedCountry) {
        if (targetedCountry == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException(targetedCountry + " cannot be null.");
        this.targetedCountry = targetedCountry;
    }
    
    public String getTargetedDomain() {
        return targetedDomain;
    }
    public void setTargetedDomain(String targetedDomain) {
        if (targetedDomain == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException(targetedDomain + " cannot be null.");
        if (!Util.isValidURL(targetedDomain)) throw new IllegalArgumentException(targetedDomain + " is not a valid URL.");
        this.targetedDomain = targetedDomain;
    }
    
    public ArrayList<BannerSize> getAvailableBannerSizeList() {
        return availableBannerSizeList;
    }
    public void setAvailableBannerSizeList(ArrayList<BannerSize> availableBannerSizeList) {
        if (availableBannerSizeList == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException(availableBannerSizeList + " cannot be null.");
        this.availableBannerSizeList = availableBannerSizeList;
    }
}
```

I am trying to write a test object of the Campaign class to a JSON file:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
Campaign testCampaign = new Campaign(1, Country.FRANCE, "https://paris.com/", new ArrayList<BannerSize>(List.of(BannerSize.x300y250, BannerSize.x600y200)));
try {
    objectMapper.writeValue(new File("D:/bids.json"), testCampaign); // this line gives the error
} catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (JsonMappingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The error is:

**com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Invalid type definition for type `ca.intfast.code.Campaign`: Failed to construct BeanSerializer for [simple type, class ca.intfast.code.Campaign]: (java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException) Unable to make public int ca.intfast.code.Campaign.getCampaignId() accessible: module code does not "exports ca.intfast.code" to module com.fasterxml.jackson.databind**

My googling possibilities are exhausted. Does anybody have an idea?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Please add the code for the `Country` class. Tip: it's a better practice to use `List` in the definition of a property because you are not committing to a specific implementation. Usee `ArrayList` in the implementation.
Note in the exception message:(java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException) Unable to make public int ca.intfast.code.Campaign.getCampaignId() accessible:

Comment: Toda! I believe, getCampaignId() is in the message just because it was encountered first. Country is an enum (I tried to provide its code, but it's impossible to mark it as "code" in the comment so it was one line, but it's just a straightforward enum).

Comment: You don't need to use *super()* in the public Campaign(int, Country, String, ArrayList<BannerSize>) constructor because you don't extend any class and in the Object class, there's no such constructor. Jackson is doing its databind with PUBLIC properties or properties which has PUBLIC *getters* and *setters*.

Comment: super() was added automatically when Eclipse created the constructor. "there's no such constructor" - you are wrong, such a constructor exists in the ancestor (Object). Calling an non-existing constructor gives an error. All the getter and setters in all the classes are public (it's their meaning to be public to access private data).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and what helped for me is exporting my packets to module-info.java

My module-info was:

```
module com.me.testjson {
requires javafx.controls;
requires javafx.fxml;
requires com.fasterxml.jackson.databind;


opens com.me.forsite to javafx.fxml;
exports com.me.forsite;
}
```

And I exported folders that Jackson required:

```
module com.me.testjson {
requires javafx.controls;
requires javafx.fxml;
requires com.fasterxml.jackson.databind;


opens com.me.forsite to javafx.fxml;
exports com.me.forsite;
exports com.me.forsite.enums;
}
```

And all worked. Maybe you should export **ca.intfast.code** like i exported **com.me.forsite.enums**